# Primefaces Drag&Drop betwwen datascroller and schedule

Tags: primefaces

I have a question about how drag&drop works between a datascroller and a schedule.

When I drag elements from a p:datalist and drop them into a p:schedule
in the drop listener of p:schedule i can get the event.getData() which corresponds to the element in my list

```
 <p:dataList  value="#{bean.list}"  var="cont"  rows="2" >
    <p:panel id="detail">
    ...
    </p:panel>
    <p:draggable for="detail" revert="true" helper="clone" cursor="move"/>
</p:dataList>

<p:timeline .... >
    <p:ajax event="drop" listener="#{bean.onDrop}" />
</p:timeline>


public void onDrop(TimelineDragDropEvent<MyObject> e) {
 e.getData() <== i get my object  from the datalist
}
```

When I run the same scenario again, this time between a p:datascroller (not lazy) and a p:schedule event.getData() returns null;

```
 <p:datascroller  value="#{bean.list}"  var="cont"  rows="2" >
    <p:panel id="detail">
    ...
    </p:panel>
    <p:draggable for="detail" revert="true" helper="clone" cursor="move"/>
</p:datascroller>

<p:timeline .... >
    <p:ajax event="drop" listener="#{bean.onDrop}" />
</p:timeline>


public void onDrop(TimelineDragDropEvent<MyObject> e) {
 e.getData() <== always null
}




Is this a bug or is it simply not possible to drag&drop between these two components?
```